# Emgucv library currentFrame.Copy

Tags: emgucv, detection, face-detection

now I am working with Face detecting using `Emgucv` library.
I am beginner for that. I have not idea about this line

```
result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
```

Can you please tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currentFrame.Copy(f.rect) is an Image that represents the image bounded by a rectangle(f.rect), which is obtained from var f which usually represents the result of the actual detection you want to implement;
Convert() Converts it to grayscale;
Resize resizes the image to 100,100 with interpolation type Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC.

You should really read more about this.